# Save a web page to Google Drive from Android phone

Tags: google-drive

If I'm browsing a web page on my android phone I'd like to save the entire web page to Google Drive in as few clicks as possible.

Best option I've seen is Share > Print > to PDF. Switch to file manager, share to Google Docs. This takes about 30 seconds and many clicks.  I do this a LOT. Looking for something that would be just a few clicks and take under 10 seconds.

Comment: In Kiwi browser (Chromium based; supports Google Chrome extensions), see if this extension works for you: https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/save-to-google-drive/gmbmikajjgmnabiglmofipeabaddhgne

Comment: @Firelord I used that extension in Chrome and its very very slow (20 to 30 seconds) and sometimes just doesn't work.   Have you've seen it work faster in Kiwi?

Comment: @Firelord Does Kiwi run on Android?  Does it support Extensions on android? (AFAIK, Chrome doesn't support Extensions on android)

Comment: I have not used that extension (I forgot to mention that). Yes, Kiwi browser does work on Android. See Kiwi Browser: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kiwibrowser.browser&hl=en&gl=US